# OpenUI5 FileUploader throws InvalidStateException in IE11 when uploading a document

Tags: sapui5

I've built a OpenUI5 based application which has a FileUploader UI element in it. This works fine in Firefox and in Chrome but in IE11, it throws a Javascript error when I upload a file.

2015-04-30 08:13:47 File upload failed:
InvalidStateError -

Here is the UI5 element XML

```
<u:FileUploader id="fileUploader" name="myFileUpload" multiple="true"
 uploadUrl="/xxxxxxx~web/AttachmentServlet" tooltip="{i18n>FileUploadTooltip}"  
placeholder="{i18n>ChooseFiles}" style="Emphasized" sendXHR="true">
</u:FileUploader>
```

I can't see any calls to AttachmentServlet in the network tab of IE11.

Why doesn't it work in IE11?

Cheers
Richard

Comment: which version do you use?

Comment: We are using openui5-runtime-1.26.7

Comment: try updating to 1.28, the error is fixed there (https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/371)

Comment: Thanks for this. I have linked to the online 1.28.5 version from ondemand.com and the issue is resolved.